# App store review: Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: swift, crash, app-store, closures

I've submit a swift app to the Apple Store. The app runs well in my iPhone (through **testflight**) and in all other **testflight** members (about 20 members). However the App Review team says it crashed when launched. The crash log is:

```
Date/Time:           2018-03-06 09:23:25.4974 +0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-06 09:23:24.8871 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100179fe8
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   simpleWeather                   0x0000000100179fe8 specialized closure #1 in LocationViewController.locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) + 335848 (LocationViewController.swift:0)
1   simpleWeather                   0x000000010017d550 partial apply for closure #1 in LocationViewController.locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) + 349520 (LocationViewController.swift:0)
2   simpleWeather                   0x00000001001332c4 specialized closure #2 in GeoRecoder.getAddress(callback:) + 45764 (struct.swift:92)
3   simpleWeather                   0x000000010012c900 closure #2 in GeoRecoder.getAddress(callback:) + 18688 (struct.swift:0)
4   simpleWeather                   0x000000010012c8c0 thunk for @callee_owned (@owned [CLPlacemark]?, @owned Error?) -> () + 18624 (struct.swift:0)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185c52a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185c52a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185c5f698 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018627b344 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186278f20 __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186198c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
11  GraphicsServices                0x0000000188044f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
12  UIKit                           0x000000018f8f15c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
13  simpleWeather                   0x00000001001304bc main + 33980 (struct.swift:13)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185cb856c start + 4
```

.....

The main problem is that I can't reproduce the crash. What should I do?

Comment: There are too many things that could go wrong, check if all the steps of the Build Phases tab of your target are correct (all files are added to copy bundle resources etc).

Comment: What's the code of `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` in ` `LocationViewController`?

Comment: You should symbolicate your crashes to get more information exactly what's going wrong. Read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

```Important: Crash reports received from App Review will be unsymbolicated, even if you included the dSYM file when uploading your archive to iTunes Connect. You will need to symbolicate any crash reports received from App Review using Xcode```